# How can I create useful fold expressions if they can't have any side effects?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make a very simple fold expression for Ruby:

```
let s:fold_indent = []

function! RubyFoldLevel(lnum)
    let l:prevline = getline(a:lnum - 1)
    let l:curline = getline(a:lnum)
    let l:nextline = getline(a:lnum + 1)

    " if l:curline=~'^\s*\(module\)\|\(class\)\|\(def\)\s'
    if l:curline=~'^\s*def\s'
        add(s:fold_indent, indent(a:lnum))
        echo s:fold_indent
        return 'a1'
    elseif l:curline=~'^\s*end\s*$'
    \ && len(s:fold_indent) > 0
    \ && indent(a:lnum) == s:fold_indent[-1]
        unlet s:fold_indent[-1]
        echo s:fold_indent
        return 's1'
    end

    return '='
endfunction
```

My plan is to add to the fold level (`"a1"`) whenever I stumble upon a `def`, then subtract from the fold level (`"s1"`) when I find the `end` *at the same level of indentation*. Here I'm attempting to do this by saving the indentation in a stack and only ending a fold when the topmost item in the stack matches the indentation level of the current line.

This doesn't work because the fold expression can't actually edit the contents of `s:fold_indent` (notice the `echo s:fold_indent`. It prints `[]` every time.) I suppose this makes sense since it's useful to be able to use the expression on any line regardless of order, however I can't work out how to write a useful fold expression without it.

Is it possible to fulfill my plan without maintaining a stack outside of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side effects in a fold expression only refer to changing text or switching windows (called *textlock* in Vim). The problem is rather that you've missed a `:call` in front of the `add()`:

```
call add(s:fold_indent, indent(a:lnum))
```

(This becomes obvious when you manually invoke the function.)

---

Nonetheless, using shared state is problematic, because you have no control where (and in which order) Vim evaluates the fold expression. For Ruby folding, I'd rather rely on the syntax highlighting (which already defines regions for `def` ... `end`) to provide the folding information (and the `syntax/ruby.vim` that ships with Vim already does).

Comment: I've tried to use `foldmethod=syntax` if that's what you mean, and that works horribly. Thanks for the explanation on why `add` wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I figured it out. My function now indents any time `module`, `class` or `def` is encountered. Any time `end` is encountered, the function iterates backwards over previous lines until a `module`, `class` or `def` is found at the same indentation level as the `end`, and if one is found it subtracts the fold level.

After a few minutes of testing and a few lines of code to handle special cases (0 or 1 line folds) it appears to work perfectly:

```
function! RubyFoldLevel(lnum)
    let l:prevline = getline(a:lnum - 1)
    let l:curline = getline(a:lnum)
    let l:nextline = getline(a:lnum + 1)
    let l:fold_starter = '^\s*\(\(module\)\|\(class\)\|\(def\)\)\s'
    let l:fold_ender = '^\s*end\s*$'

    " Prevent 1-line folds.
    if indent(a:lnum - 1) == indent(a:lnum + 1)
    \ && l:prevline =~ l:fold_starter
    \ && l:nextline =~ l:fold_ender
        return "="
    end

    if l:prevline=~l:fold_starter
    \ && !(l:curline =~ l:fold_ender && indent(a:lnum - 1) == indent(a:lnum))
        return 'a1'
    end

    if l:nextline=~l:fold_ender
    \ && !(l:curline =~ l:fold_starter && indent(a:lnum) == indent(a:lnum + 1))
        let l:cursor = a:lnum + 1

        while 1
            let l:cursor = prevnonblank(l:cursor - 1)

            " Fold starter found at this indentation level.
            if indent(l:cursor) == indent(a:lnum + 1)
            \ && getline(l:cursor)=~l:fold_starter
                return 's1'
            end

            " No fold starter found at this indentation level.
            if indent(l:cursor) < indent(a:lnum + 1)
                break
            end
        endwhile
    end

    return '='
endfunction

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=RubyFoldLevel(v:lnum)
```

Needless to say, this fold expression will only work on source files with "correct" indentation.